# How to set the precision of the result when converting a double to string using std::to_string()?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any way to set the precision of the result when converting a double to string **using `std::to_string()`**?

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/a/16606128/2436175

Answer (score 53, accepted):

No.

> Returns: Each function returns a string object holding the character representation of the value of
> its argument that would be generated by calling `sprintf(buf, fmt, val)` with a format specifier of
> `"%d"`, `"%u"`, `"%ld"`, `"%lu"`, `"%lld"`, `"%llu"`, `"%f"`, `"%f"`, or `"%Lf"`, respectively, where buf designates
> an internal character buffer of sufficient size.

Answer (score 10):

I was just looking for a solution to this as I was overloading the `std::cout <<` operator and therefore it would have been tricky to do the `std::stringstream` workaround. I solved my problem by using the `std::substr()` function to locate the decimal and take a chosen number of digits past it.

```
std::string trimmedString = std::to_string(doubleVal).substr(0, std::to_string(doubleVal).find(".") + precisionVal + 1);
```

This will give you "precisionVal" 0's after your number.

Ex:

```
double doubleVal = 3;
int preisionVal = 2
```

`3.000000` becomes `3.00`

Comment: Note that this truncates rather than rounding

Comment: Actually, this is the right answer to the question. `std::to_string` makes 6 decimal places after the decimal point (the default precision is 6), eg `std::to_string(1.2)` returns "1.200000" rather than just "1.2". This answer truncates, but that's how to set the precision unless otherwise requested. If you want to round, you can freely do it beforehand.

Answer (score 6):

I believe that using `std::stringstream` with `setprecision` would be the most flexible/portable choice, but if you know your data, as an workaround, you could try to substring the `to_string` result. For example:

```
std::string seriesSum(int n)
{
    double sum = 0, div = 1;
    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
      sum += 1.0 / div;
      div += 3;
    }

    return std::to_string(round(sum * 100)/100).substr(0,4);
}
```

In the code above I'm printing with two decimal places `0.00` by taking the first 4 digits of the string, but it only works because I know the integer part is never going above one digit. You could also use `string.find()` to search for the decimal separator and use it's position to calculate the size of the substring, making it a bit more dynamic.

Comment: Do not forget to include `std::fixed` together the `std::setprecision(...)` to avoid getting results in scientific notation

Answer (score 4):

You can't do it with `std::to_string` but C++20 [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) allows you to control precision, e.g.

```
std::string s = std::format("{.10}", M_PI); // s == "3.141592654"
```

Godbolt: https://www.godbolt.org/z/4aG8h658d.

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of C++20 `std::format`.

Comment: nice.. should be using std:numbers though since it's c++20:

https://www.godbolt.org/z/qMfGsEhjv

Answer (score -1):

Personally, I prefer another algorithm. First, calculate fraction places count and second, set that value as precision to **stringstream** object.

```cpp
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string to_string_ld(long double number) {
    long double temp = number;
    long double integerPart = floor(temp);
    int fractionCounter = 0;

    while (temp - integerPart > 0) {
        temp = temp * 10;
        integerPart = floor(temp);
        fractionCounter++;
    }

    fractionCounter = max(1, fractionCounter);

    stringstream stream;
    stream.precision(fractionCounter);
    stream << fixed << number;
    return stream.str();
}

int main() {
    long double value = 1.123456789;
    cout << to_string_ld(value) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Will produce this output:

```
1.123456789
```

Comment: that's really overcomplicating things.. set @vitaut answer above.