# Set precision of std::to_string when converting floating point values

Tags: c++, string, c++11, double, floating

In C++11, [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) defaults to 6 decimal places when given an input value of type `float` or `double`. What is the recommended, or most elegant, method for changing this precision?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

There is no way to change the precision via `to_string()` but the [`setprecision`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) IO manipulator could be used instead:

```
#include <sstream>

template <typename T>
std::string to_string_with_precision(const T a_value, const int n = 6)
{
    std::ostringstream out;
    out.precision(n);
    out << std::fixed << a_value;
    return std::move(out).str();
}
```

Comment: Nice, but it'd be great to be able to do this without creating a temp string. :/ Especially in a very, very tight inner loop.

Comment: isn't the inner string implicitly moved by being a returned rval?

Comment: I get "3e+01" for the 33.33~ case, even only using n = 1.

Comment: To ensure the number of digits, also std::fixed must be passed. See sample in http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iomanip/setprecision/

Comment: Using string at all in a tight inner loop is a bad idea. Memory allocations are super slow. You are trying to use 1 memory allocation instead of having 2 memory allocations by avoiding a temporary. You try to avoid any memory allocations if you want performance by using sprintf and a stack allocated buffer. :-)

Comment: You don't need `iomanip` for this: just use `out.precision(n); out << a_value;`. Using `iomanip` isn't even less typing.

Comment: If you automatically want to choose the best available precision you can use `const unsigned int digits = std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10;` instead of the integer n

Comment: When I tried `float x = 107.2; cout<<to_string(x)` gives 107.199997. Is this normal?

Comment: Could please someone confirm this:
"
isn't the inner string implicitly moved by being a returned rval? – 
Jules G.M.
Aug 18, 2014 at 22:40 
"? It's an interesting statement and I think it's correct? Could please someone confirm?