# Is std::to_string guaranteed to include a decimal point when converting floating point values?

Tags: c++, c++11

With the below code,

```
int main() {
    for(;;) {
        float d;
        cin >> d;
        cout << std::to_string(d) << endl;
    }
}
```

`to_string` seems to always return a string containing a decimal point followed by six digits. Is this behavior guaranteed (excluding `nan` and `infinity`)?

According to [*cplusplus.com*](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/to_string/), "as many digits are written as needed to represent the integral part, followed by the decimal-point character and six decimal digits".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> `to_string` seems to always return a string containing a decimal point followed by six digits. Is this behavior guaranteed (excluding `nan` and `infinity`)?

Yes. The output of `std::to_string` is controlled by the output `std::sprintf`, whose default precision is 6.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string,

> 7,8) Converts a floating point value to a string with the same content as what `std::sprintf(buf, "%f", value)` would produce for sufficiently large `buf`.

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf, (emphasis mine)

> f, F
>
> converts floating-point number to the decimal notation in the style [-]ddd.ddd.
>
> Precision specifies the minimum number of digits to appear after the decimal point character. **The default precision is 6**.

---

#### Caveat

The decimal point is not used as the decimal marker in all locales. You might get a different character for the decimal marker depending on the locale. But a decimal marker will be there regardless of locale.

Comment: I would add the following recipe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values?rq=1

Comment: These are undoubtedly the rules in effect.... but why does the comment concerning "the alternative implementation" of `sprintf` provide a guarantee on `to_string`?

Comment: @BenVoigt, the *alternative implementation* is not relevant to the answer. I'll remove it.

Comment: @RSahu: But the alternative implementation was where a decimal point gets added even when there are no decimal digits.

Comment: @BenVoigt, that's true. But that applies only if the format used is `"%#f"`, which is not the case here.

Comment: Oh, ok, because there are 6 decimals after the floating-point, it doesn't matter that the floating-point would be omitted if there were no following digits.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the decimal point is guaranteed when `"%f"` is used, with 6 digits of precision. My understanding is that the `#` comes into play only when you use 0 digits of precision - `"%#10.0f"` will add the decimal point but `"%10.0f"` will not

Comment: "For a, A, e, E, f, F, g, and  G  conversions,  the  result  of  converting  a  ﬂoating-point  number  always contains  a  decimal-point  character,  even  if  no  digits  follow  it.   (Normally,  a decimal-point character appears in the result of these conversions only if a digit follows  it.)   For  g  and  G  conversions,  trailing  zeros  are  not  removed  from  the result.  For other conversions, the behavior is undeﬁned."  So it seems that if the value is within .0000005 of an integer, it could be printed with no decimal digits and if so, no decimal point would be output either.

Comment: Or maybe the trailing zeros *aren't* removed without `#`.

Comment: @BenVoigt, the trailing zeros are removed when g or G conversion is used without the `#`. When used with `#`, the trailing zeros are retained.

Comment: Decimal point is **NOT** guaranteed, see: https://github.com/nlohmann/json/issues/51

Comment: @Delgan, The decimal point is guaranteed but the dot character is not guaranteed. That depends on the locale.

Comment: @RSahu I think "decimal point" specifically refers to the dot character. Quoting Wikipedia about [decimal separator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_separator): "Any such symbol can be called a decimal mark, decimal marker or decimal sign. But symbol-specific names are also used; **decimal point** and **decimal comma** refer to an (either baseline or middle) dot and comma respectively"

Answer (score 3):

No. The decimal point can also be a comma, depending on the computer on which the program is run (controled by `$LANG` on Linux or other means on Windows). The C++ documentation says:

> std::to_string relies on the current locale for formatting purposes

This means that when e.g. run in Germany, std::to_string uses a comma, while when run on a computer in the US, it uses a point as separator. To enforce a dot as decimal separator, you must set the locale before calls to *to_string*:

```
#include <clocale>
std::setlocale(LC_NUMERIC, "C")
```