# Convert string to double and then double to string without losing precision

Tags: c++, string, c++11

I am using C++11. I have real world coordinates such as `38.0098662, 23.7805398` in a text file, meaning 2 `double` variables. I parse that file with C++ and I convert the `strings` to `double` with the `stod()` method. When I tried printing the values with `count.precision(9);`, the values seemed to be the same as in the text file.

Then, I want to convert those `double` values back to `string` format. For that I use `to_string()` method. However that seems to be changing the value slightly. For example:

```
38.0098662, 23.7805398  became
38.009866,  23.780540
// in fact, every number is xx.yyyyyy
```

I don't understand why this is so hard to do with C++11. Why do I lose precision for no reason ? How can I do this properly ? Every question I looked into pointed to `to_string()` method, which is what I am using.

Comment: _"I have done the exact same thing in python, and I didn't see this behaviour."_ Not sure what the relevance of Python is here. That's a different language entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone had the same problem as you had.
Simply set the precision of the std::ostringstream to your desired size and return it as std::string.

Here is a reference to an older question which shows the implementation:

[Look at this!](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -3):

It cause from compiler code optimization(for fastest run).
Sometimes C++ compiler optimizes floating point number processing, and loses a bit precision.

Comment: This has nothing to do with optimisations. Anyway, how is the compiler supposed to "optimise" the value read from a file at runtime?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289157(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: gcc also has its optimization for floating point model.

This optimization apply when value assign in variables.

Comment: Sorry, you're confused.

Comment: The article you posted states some else. *An optimizing C++ compiler [...] arranges the machine instructions in such a way as to improve efficiency and/or reduce size.* The compiler could not possibly optimize a value that has not been part of the program at the time the compilation occurs.