# Need help to understand where i am going wrong with strings

Tags: c++, string, templates, stl

In c++ we have `std::to_string` which converts int/float/double to strings. So just to test my understanding of templates I tried the code below:

```
#include "iostream"
#include "sstream"
#include "string"
using std::cout;

template <typename T>
std::string getString(const T& data){
    std::stringstream ss;
    cout << '\n' << data << '\n';
    ss << data;
    std::string s;
    ss >> s;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc , char** argv){
    cout << getString(1.0000011);
    cout <<' '<<std::to_string(1.0000011);
    return 0;    
}
```

However, the output doesn't make sense, `to_string` gives me `1.0000011`, whereas `getString` gets 1 and gives me 1. As I am using templates shouldn't `getString` get 1.0000011 as well and give me 1.0000011 too?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `std::setprecision` in the `<iomanip>` header to set the precision that `std::stringstream` will use when formatting numeric data.

For example:

```
std::stringstream ss;
ss << std::setprecision(9) << data;
cout << ss.str();
```

Will print:

```
1.0000011
```

Here's a quick demo online: [cpp.sh/9v7xf](http://cpp.sh/9v7xf)

As a side note, you don't have to create a `string` and output from the `stringstream` - you can replace the last 3 lines in `getString()` with:

```
return ss.str();
```

Comment: Consider using `std::numeric_limits<T>::digits10` instead of 9.

Answer (score 2):

Numeric values are often truncated for appearance. You can supply the [std::fixed](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed) manipulator from the iomanip standard header to avoid this issue.

```
#include "iomanip" // <- Add this header
#include "iostream"
#include "sstream"
#include "string"
using std::cout;

template <typename T>
std::string getString(const T& data)
{
    std::stringstream ss;
    cout << '\n' << data << '\n';
    ss << std::fixed << data;
    //    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Add this
    std::string s;
    ss >> s;
    return s;
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    cout << getString(1.0000011);
    cout << ' ' << std::to_string(1.0000011);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: using 'std::fixed` alone truncates the string, so it is `1.000001`.

Answer (score 1):

`<iomanip>` needs included, and `std::setprecision` must be used when outputting float values to streams. Using your example, this looks like:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip> //include this.
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

template <typename T>
std::string getString(const T& data){
    std::ostringstream ss;
    ss << std::setprecision(8);
    std::cout << std::setprecision(8);
    std::cout << data << '\n';
    ss << data;
    return ss.str();
}

int main(int argc , char** argv){
    std::cout << getString(1.0000011) << "\n";
    std::cout << std::to_string(1.0000011) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Which prints:

```
1.0000011
1.0000011
1.000001
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

**Note how `to_string` alone truncates the floating point number!!!** I suspect this is undesired behavior, but `to_string` cannot be manipulated directly, so...

If desired, you can fix this with the solution [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values).

Otherwise, just use `std:set_precision()` when inserting into streams for precisely converted strings.

Comment: I would use `std::ostringstream` instead.  And you are using `std::setprecision()` only on `std::cout` but not on the `ss` stream as well.

Comment: @Remy Lebeau , what is your reason for chosing std::ostringstream

Comment: @Arup `std::stringstream` is designed  for both input and output, but  `getString()` only needs output, which is what `std::ostringstream` is designed for.