# Convert float to std::string without losing precision. Also I don't want to use sprintf

Tags: c++

I want to convert float value i.e 3.14159267 in std::string
I don't want to use sprintf

```
#include <iostream>   // std::cout
#include <string>     // std::string, std::to_string

int main ()
{
  std::string pi = "pi is " + std::to_string(3.14159267);
  std::cout<<pi<<std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I got result as 
    3.141593

Comment: Well, you can't. You always loose some precision when converting between floats and decimal representations.

Comment: @freakish no you don't, if you do it right.

Comment: won't `stringstream` just handle this?

Comment: And you can always put pi directlly to cout (or another stream) and increase display precision.

Comment: Dup targ isn't valid, the dup is about printing a full precision `double`. This question clearly prints out a string, so precision is lost because of `std::to_string`, not by `std::cout`. Reopening.

Comment: See this question..
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values

Comment: You talk about not losing precision. That is tough. The number you want to have is "`3.14159267"` which you write down like a floating point number. Sadly this number is not representable as a floating point number. The closest IEEE 754 binary64 number (approximated as a decimal number) is `3.14159267000000008707161214260850101709365844726562...` So no matter what you do, you already lost your decimal precision from the start. Unless you state up to which precision you want the number to be equivalent.

Comment: You probably do not understand the difference between a number and its representation. You should ask yourself “how many numbers are between any two numbers?”.

Comment: the float is coming from user input? I think it would help if you say why you need this and why you cant simply write `std::string pi = "3.14159267";`. Or is this really just about printing the float value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest you call `snprintf` with format specifier `"%.16g"` - that prints a `double` in decimal with 16 significant digits of precision. See [Number of Digits Required For Round-Trip Conversions](https://www.exploringbinary.com/number-of-digits-required-for-round-trip-conversions/) for more details. E.g.:

```
inline std::string as_string(double value) {
    char buf[32];
    return std::string(buf, std::snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%.16g", value));
}
```

---

`*printf` functions are fundamental conversion routines, everything else uses these.

`std::to_string` in GNU C++ standard library does:

```
inline string to_string(double __val)  {
  const int __n =  __gnu_cxx::__numeric_traits<double>::__max_exponent10 + 20;
  return __gnu_cxx::__to_xstring<string>(&std::vsnprintf, __n, "%f", __val);
}
```

`std::ostream` also calls `*snprintf` under the hood to format numbers.

---

Also note that `3.14159267` is `double`. A `float` constant requires `f` suffix, e.g. `3.14159267f`.

Answer (score 4):

If you only want ot print out:

```
std::cout<< std::setprecision(9) << 3.14159267 << std::endl;
```

If you want to set the precision of string:

```
  double pi = 3.14159265359;
  std::stringstream stream;
  stream << std::setprecision(9) << pi;
  std::string pi_string = stream.str();
  std::cout<< "Pi:" << pi_string << std::endl;
```

Comment: I won't come to know what will be the length of the float value, thus I can't set the precision in advance.

Comment: You do not need to know the length. Float has always a precision of 6. So you can leave that std::setprecisio out. By the way: your PI (3.14159267) needs double presicion

Comment: Your first example may not work as expected because some stream manipulators are sticky and someone might have done `std::cout << std::fixed;` before this line. IMO, using `std::ostream` for number formatting is much subtler that it seems and too verbose. Try `std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(9) << 0.000000000314159267 << '\n';`

Answer (score 3):

Theoretically, this should work with a C++17 compliant compiler (and is supposed to be fast and locale-independent):

```
#include <charconv>

const double pi = 3.14159267;
const int prec = 6;
char buffer[100];

auto [ptr, ec] = std::to_chars(buffer, std::end(buffer),
    pi, std::chars_format::fixed, prec);
```

Unfortunately, it doesn't, not even with the trunk version of `gcc` or `clang`. Seems that [P0067R5](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0067r5.html) is not that obvious to implement, see also the cppreference [compiler support](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) (search for "P0067R5") or [this reddit thread](https://www.reddit.com/r/cpp/comments/ankc50/when_will_gcc_have_stdfrom_chars_for_floating/).