# How to avoid `std::to_string()` making a very small double number to 0?

Tags: c++, floating-point, double, c++14, tostring

I have a requirement to store very small double numbers into a string format and then later reverse them. However, when I try to run `std::to_string()` on a small number like `4.7816457028269855e-143` then it simply makes it 0.

I referred [Set precision of std::to_string when converting floating point values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values) and its linked duplicate. But will setting the precision to a very large number solve this issue in all the platforms?

How to fix this issue?
Using any alternatives to `to_string()` is fine.

Comment: Hmm, it's not even that small, as DBL_MIN = 2.2250738585072013830902327173324040642192159804623318306e-308

Comment: If you are looking for high fidelity for round trip, and you want text rather than binary, and you don't care if the text isn't very legible, you can use the floating point hexadecimal format.

Comment: @Eljay or if you can require new enough compilers, you could use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem is not precision, but the format. You want to print in scientific format (with exponent) but `std::to_string()` uses the fixed format by default and I'm not aware of any way to change this.

However, streams use scientific if appropriate or you can force it with [`std::scientific`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed):

```
std::ostringstream oss;
oss << 4.7816457028269855e-143;
std::string numberAsString = oss.str(); // stores "4.78165e-143"
```

Of course you can increae the [precision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/setprecision) in addition to this.

If for whatever reason you don't want to use scientific format, you can use the fixed format with a high enough precision. "High enough" meaning more than 142 in this case, because there will be 142 leading zeroes:

```
oss << std::fixed << std::setprecision(142 + x);
```

But the scientific format is better suited, I guess.

Comment: I don't have any requirement to store it as a scientific format. It can be any format. Main concern is that, it should not convert it to 0.0. Can you edit your answer accordingly.

Comment: @iammilind And that's exactly what this code does. Did you try it? Btw. you **need** scientific format. How many leading zeroes would this number have in fixed format?

Answer (score 2):

As already mentioned, it's impossible to achieve this with `std::to_string`, but outputting the number to `std::ostringstream` with large enough precision will solve your issue.

The required precision can be computed in a cross-platform way using the C++ Standard Library facilities, specifically the `std::numeric_limits<T>::max_digits10` constant: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max_digits10

For example:

```
std::string to_string_exact(double x) {
  std::ostringstream os;
  os << std::setprecision(std::numeric_limits<double>::max_digits10) << x;
  return os.str();
}
```

See also https://possiblywrong.wordpress.com/2015/06/21/floating-point-round-trips/ for some caveats.

Comment: Even without setting the precision, I see that the `ostringstream` solves the problem. However is it cross platform?

Comment: It's in the std namespace so obviously it must be cross platform, because it's defined by the C++ standard