# Store The Result of Division of Two Doubles in a String up to a Particular Precision in C++

Tags: c++, string, double, precision, tostring

*The Question in brief:*

**How to print the result of a double division in a string with a certain precision.**

*The Description:*

Suppose I want to store the result of a double division in a string, one way to do it would be like this:

```
double a = 22.0;
double b = 7.0;
double c = a / b;           // storing the result in temporary var
string str = to_string(c);  // the string to be printed
cout << str;                // this prints 3.142857
```

To print the number with a particular precision, I could simply use:

```
cout << setprecision(20) << c;  // this prints 3.1428571428571427937
```

Now I want to store this double with 20 precision in a string, I am not aware about any technique to do so.

This is my desired outcome:

```
string str = to_string(c); // the string to be printed
/*
    some operation with str here to make it print 
    upto 20 precision
*/
cout << str;               // this should print 3.1428571428571427937
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values

Comment: 20 digits is more than you can meaningfully expect from a double. According to an old professor of mine, print that many and you'd be lying. We were warned that if we did that on a problem, we'd get a 0 for that problem.

Comment: @AviBerger, 20 was just an example, thanks for the information though.