# to_wstring().size() isn't behaving as expected

Tags: c++, wstring

I have a double variable, the contents of which need to be converted into a string. I need to calculate, how long that string would end up being, so I tried using size(), but that leads to unexpected results.

From this:

```
double test_double;
test_double = 12.34;
std::wstring test_string = L"12.34";
std::wcout << L"string is: " << test_string << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"length of string is: " << test_string.size() << std::endl; //this shows expected result
std::wcout << L"double is: " << test_double << std::endl;
std::wcout << L"length of double is: " << (std::to_wstring(test_double)).size() << std::endl; //and this makes me wonder
```

I get this output:

```
string is: 12.34
length of string is: 5
double is: 12.34
length of double is: 9
```

The strings seem to end up being identical, but the result of a conversion is different for some reason. Am I missing something?

Comment: What do you get if you print the value of `std::to_wstring(test_double)`?

Comment: [to_wstring](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) uses a default `%f` format, that probably results in `12.340000`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation for std::to_wstring (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) states that it "Converts a floating point value to a wide string as if by `std::swprintf(buf, sz, L"%f", value)`".

If we look at the documentation for `swprintf` (https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fwprintf) and look at the `f` format specifier, we see that it defaults to 6 digits of precision. This is leading to the string `12.340000`.

`std::cout` is going to (by default) format `double`s according to the `defaultfloat` IO manipulator described here: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/fixed. Importantly, you can see in their example that it will truncate zeroes and will thus produce `12.34` in this case.

When you explicitly convert to a string with `std::to_wstring`, you are now providing an explicit string to `std::cout` and so it doesn't try to be clever and truncate for you. When you give a double to `std::cout`, it has to make a decision as to what is the appropriate way to display the number (fixed digits, scientific, etc.). It turns out that the default behavior is simply not what you want in this case it seems.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer! I can see why all of this is happening now... But I cannot wrap my head around how to actually fix any of this. Is there a way to lower the precision for the conversion?

Comment: If you have C++20 look at [std::format](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/format) it allows you to specify options for [formatting output](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format/formatter#Standard_format_specification))

Comment: If you do not have C++20, you could do what is described in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16605967/set-precision-of-stdto-string-when-converting-floating-point-values. Clunky, but it works. Write a wrapper function.

Comment: You guys are a blessing, thank you all for your efforts!