# Loss of Precision when Converting Double to String in C++

Tags: c++, string

So I know `setprecision(int n)` should be used when printing a double value with precision `n`. However, I've run into a problem on a project that I'm working on that is akin to this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    double var = 1.0000001;
    cout << setprecision(10)<< var << endl;
    string str = to_string(var);
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output:

```
1.0000001
1.000000
```

In the project I'm working on, I need to save the double value as a string, and it will occasionally need more than six decimal places of precision. Here, precision is clearly lost in the conversion. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [The precision of std::to\_string(double)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520309/the-precision-of-stdto-stringdouble)

Comment: Use a `stringstream` instead of `to_string` so you can use the formatting options.

Comment: Two pointers: 1) `int *p`, 2) don't use `std::to_string` if you need to manage precision.

Comment: To save the full precision of a `double`, you need more than 10 digits. The 1990 revision of C language provides a constant (`#include <float.h>` or `<cfloat>` called `DBL_DIG` which is almost what we want: it gives the maximum number of digits in a decimal number that the `double` type can preserve. C99 added another one: `DECIMAL_DIG`. That one tells us the maximum number of decimal digits we need to exactly preserve the largest floating point type in text.  C11 adds `DBL_DECIMAL_DIG`.

Comment: For a 64 bit IEEE 754 double, we need 17 decimal digits to preserve the value.

Comment: Ha, I found that exact value by messing around with the levels of precision. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `std::stringstream`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main(void) {
    double var = 1.0000001;
    cout << setprecision(10)<< var << endl;
    stringstream ss;
    ss << setprecision(10) << var;
    string str;
    ss >> str;
    cout << str << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: BTW in VS2015 this call is translated to formatting string like this `sprintf_s("%.*g", 10, var)`. It was helpful for me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get the **full precision** of your double without limiting it to a specific value (implied by your "occasionally need more than six decimal places"), and if you are using the **Boost** libraries, you can also try this following alternative:

```
#include <boost/lexical_cast.hpp>    
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost;
using namespace std;    

int main() {
    double var = 1.0000001;   
    cout << lexical_cast<string>(var) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

This has proven useful in one of my applications where precision did matter, and where the `std::stringstream` approach was not very convenient and elegant due to usage of some specific logging function wrappers. You can find **more information** about `boost::lexical_cast` and how it deals with internal representations [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/boost_lexical_cast.html).

Obviously, if you are not currently using Boost in your project, this approach is *overkill*.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
#include <sstream>
#include <string>

// In some function:
double d = 453.23;
std::ostringstream os;
os << d;
std::string str = os.str();
```