# How to use std::to_string function to format float as “x.0”

Tags: c++, c++11

I am using std::to_string function to convert float to string.

```
 float number = 30.0f;  // this number will vary
```

when i convert the float number to string

```
 std::to_string(number);
```

the std::cout shows the result as 30.000000

i want the result as 30.0 and remove the extra zeros.

Comment: See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string .. note that to_string does not have support for this use-case. (The link hints at a suitable replacement function.)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The precision of std::to\_string(double)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14520309/the-precision-of-stdto-stringdouble)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`std::to_string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string) doesn't support this, and in fact is not generally great for arbitrary floating-point values.

Since your question is tagged [c++11](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b11), there are two ways I'm aware of. Firstly, you have `std::stringstream`, which is type safe and will work with arbitrary types:

```cpp
#include <sstream>

// ...

float number = 30.0f;

std::ostringstream oss;
oss << std::setprecision(1) << number;
std::string result = oss.str();
```

Alternatively, you have [`std::snprintf`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fprintf), which requires converting through a `char` buffer of a given size:

```cpp
float number = 30.0f;

char buffer[20];  // maximum expected length of the float
std::snprintf(buffer, 20, "%.1f", number);
std::string str(buffer);
```

From C++17 you may use [`std::to_chars`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/to_chars) instead in a similar way to `std::snprintf`, and from C++20 you may use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format).